# AngularJS: Replace element template on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I got the following problem: My customer wants my angular directive to change the looks completely on focus. That means for me, I will need to replace the template completely when the user clicks that element. I was not able to find an answer in internet, so decided to ask.

I tried to pass the "unfocused" template in the template section of the directive, and bind to the focus event in link like this:

```
   post: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('focus',function(event){
          element.html('<span..../span>');
          $compile(element)(scope);
        });
   }
```

But it produces an error (input is the "unfocused" template)

```
Uncaught Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives 
[ngModel, ngModel] asking for 'ngModel' controller on: <input....
```

The solution needs to be compatible with Angular 1.2 which I have to use.

Comment: I don't know how complex your template is, but one possible approach would be to simply have one template and use `ng-if` to change looks on focus.

Comment: I have considered it, but there is a small problem. The form validation framework which I have to use must have an "input" element as a root element of each value directive of the form in the moment the form is submitted. In case of <span ng-if...><input...></input></span>, would the input or the span count as the root element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-if` will not render the element at all if the condition is false.
In your comment you have the input nested in the span, so the span is the root element. You can have both, the span and the input as top level elements in your template.

```
<input ng-if="focusCondition"/>
<span ng-if="!focusCondition"></span>
```

Then the element that is rendered should be the root element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-switch directive and display only those templates which have to be shown on focus.

Comment: please add more explaination to your answer so that the QO knows what exactly to do